# Angular - Binding data to dropdownlist never clears out previous items on updating (keeps old items plus add new)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, data-binding

Hopefully a simple Angular binding question.
I have a TextBox on my Angular 4 [x.component.html] that has an (input) event tied to it, so each time the user types in a character into the textbox it reaches out to a method in the [x.component.ts] typescript file - which then retrieves data from a service to populate a local array of data in the typescript file - which is bound to a dropdownlist on the [x.component.html].  This process functionally works fine.
However the problem I am having is that when it updates the data in the local array, it is not clearing out the previous data in the dropdown, so the dropdown list ends up getting populated with lots of duplicate data.  Has anyone experienced this same problem before?  The local array of items seems to have the correct number of items in it, it just seems to keep populating the dropdownlist with the items without ever clearing the previous.
Thanks so much for your help.

Please note I have cut the code down to only the relevant parts for brevity.

[x.component.ts]

```
export class CreateComponent {

  testService: TestService;

  valueList: testValue[];

  constructor(testService: TestService) {
    this.testService = TestService;
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  FieldChanged(event: any, controlNameToPopulate: string){
    if (event.target.value.length >= 9) {
      this.testService.getRecords(event.target.value).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        if (data.length != 0){
          document.getElementById(controlNameToPopulate).hidden = false;

            //this.valueList.slice();
            this.valueList = data;
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[x.component.html]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <nb-card>
        <nb-card-header>Testing with Updating dropdownlist</nb-card-header>
        <nb-card-body>
          <form [formGroup]="formGrp">

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Quick search</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="width: 50%" id="txtbx_ValTest" formControlName="testVal" (change)="FieldChanged($event, 'ddValuesToUpdate')">
                  <select id="ddValuesToUpdate" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="width: 50%" hidden>
                      <option *ngFor="let val of valueList" [value]="val.id">{{val.id}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>

              <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
        </nb-card-body>
      </nb-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? How are you populating the array?

Comment: I have now added the code snippets for the data into the question.  I am populating the array from a service call, and the array appears to be populating with the correct number of items each time when I am debugging.

Comment: It doesn't clear the previous when your select is open? What if you close the select and re-open

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with whether the select / options dropdownlist is open or closed or selected.  It seems that during binding it is not clearing out the previous items in the select dropdownlist items.  In other words, each time a user types a charcter into the textbox it should be removing the items that were in the dropdown box and updating it with the items coming back from the service call, but it seems to just be adding them the the current/previous items instead of replacing the items.

Comment: Odd, what if you remove `document.getElementById(controlNameToPopulate).hidden = false;`

Comment: Example:  User types in 'abcdefghi' and service call returns a list of 45 items to populate the dropdownlist.  Now when the type in an additional character into the textbox to make it 'abcdefghij' the service call would return a list of 28 items, and the dropdown list should only now have the 28 items, but it is currently adding the 28 items to the previous 45 items (for a total of 73 items).  It should be working like a type-ahead functionality where it is reducing the number of items to choose from from the dropdownlist, but it is adding to it instead.

Comment: removing the .hidden = false is just making the control element visible to the user unfortunately so it should not affect the item binding..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161747/discussion-between-codingriot-and-llai).

Comment: @CodingRiot Could you try using the spread operator `...` to try and assign a new array object on each subscription like this, `this.valueList = [ ...data];` ?

Comment: @amal, that did it, thanks a million.  I haven't ever used that before, that works great.  Can you please post that here and I will mark it as the answer.